# How config.use_env_variable, Object.keysand readdirSync are useful in finding models in node js code?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to Node JS and came across the following code. Tried my best and googled a lot to understand this, but couldn't. Can anyone explain this?

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = require('path');
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
 const basename = path.basename(__filename);
 const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
 const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
 const db = {};
 var sequelize;
 if (config.use_env_variable) {
 sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
 } else {
 sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, 
config.password, config);
}

fs
.readdirSync(__dirname)
.filter(file => {
return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && 
       (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
})
.forEach(file => {
const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
if (db[modelName].associate) {
db[modelName].associate(db);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.use_env_variable` is not using for finding the models. This is used to identify which database configuration you want to use. Either from sequelize configuration file `config.json` or from .env variables.

Below code is used for identify the model.

```
fs
.readdirSync(__dirname)
.filter(file => {
return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && 
       (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
})
.forEach(file => {
   const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
   db[model.name] = model; //putting model into array
});
```

`Object.keys` is using to find all the keys from array db.

Comment: Please upvote and mark is the correct answer if you understand.